# How to Coalesce a CSV file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Im working on a python code where the script will do a coalesce on the first Account column and populate it in another column Account_new:
For example:

```
Original:
Account Description 
1001
1000     asdsa
          sfsfd
         sdsfsaf
2000      asdasd
           asdsd

Result:
Account Description  Account_new 
1001                 1001 
1000     asdsa       1000
          sfsfd      1000
         sdsfsaf     1000  
2000      asdasd     2000
           asdsd     2000
```

This is a rough example. The csv is tab delimited. The problem I am facing is that the first account number is not getting captured. The results Im getting is :

```
Result:
Account Description  Account_new 
1001                  
1000     asdsa       1000
          sfsfd      1000
         sdsfsaf     1000  
2000      asdasd     2000
           asdsd     2000
```

The code is not capturing few of the lines which have data. The first line is not getting captured and it is skipping few lines in between.

```
Code:
import csv
import sys
import os
i=0
file=input("File Name:")
acc=""
print("\n")
print ("Your file name is:"+file)
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore'), delimiter='\t')
resultfile=open('result_data.csv', 'w',newline='')
#rowHeaders = reader.fieldnames
rowHeaders=['Account', 'Type', 'Date', 'Document Number', 'Name', 'Debit', 'Credit', 'Balance','Account_new']
csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(resultfile, rowHeaders,delimiter='\t')
csvWriter.writeheader()
for line in reader:
    if(line["Account"]==""):
        line["Account_new"]=acc
    acc=line["Account"]
    line["Account_new"]=acc
    csvWriter.writerow(line)
resultfile.close()
```

As i am new to python it would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop, if the "Account" field is empty in current line, you want to use the value from the previous line (or the line before) so you added the `if(line["Account"=="")` check.

But then after this `if` check, you again pick the value from current line (irrespective of whether it is available) and assign it to "Account_new". This should be done in the `else` part of the above `if` check.

Something like:

```
for line in reader:
    if(line["Account"]==""):
        line["Account_new"]=acc
    else:
        acc=line["Account"]
        line["Account_new"]=acc
    csvWriter.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimum viable example based on your code. I abstract away from the file input/output operations, and instead work with a string.

```
input_file = """
Account,Description
1001,
1000,asdsa
,sfsfd
,sdsfsaf
2000,asdasd
,asdsd
"""

reader = csv.DictReader(test.splitlines()) # I apply the `splitlines` method here because I'm reading from a string.


for line in reader:
    if(line["Account"]==""):
        line["Account_new"]=acc
    acc=line["Account"]
    line["Account_new"]=acc
    print(line) # Print instead of writing to file.
```

However, the output does not correspond to what you report:

```
OrderedDict([('Account', '1001'), ('Description', ' '), ('Account_new', '1001')])
OrderedDict([('Account', '1000'), ('Description', 'asdsa'), ('Account_new', '1000')])
OrderedDict([('Account', ''), ('Description', 'sfsfd'), ('Account_new', '')])
OrderedDict([('Account', ''), ('Description', 'sdsfsaf'), ('Account_new', '')])
OrderedDict([('Account', '2000'), ('Description', 'asdasd'), ('Account_new', '2000')])
OrderedDict([('Account', ''), ('Description', 'asdsd'), ('Account_new', '')])
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
Account Description Account New
1001                1001
1000    asdsa       1000 
        sfsfd
        sdsfsaf
2000    asdasd      2000
        asdsd
```

I suggest the following logic in your `for` loop: If you come across a line with a non-empty `Account` field, point `acc` at that value. Then use `acc` to set your `Account_new` field, and continue doing so on all subsequent lines, until you reach a new non-empty `Account` field. Like so:

```
for line in reader:
  if(line["Account"]!=""):
    acc=line["Account"]
  line["Account_new"] = acc
  csvWriter.writerow(line
```